# Thread and Observer Pattern VS Swingworker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, observer-pattern, swingworker

As mentioned in the title,
I am working on Swing which I use Swingworker with it in order to keep Swing responsive. I just wonder another alternative solution that ***Can I use Thread and Observer Pattern to keep Swing responsive?***. 
I have not tried that solution (Thread and Observer) yet because of time limit.
Thank You.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: As mentioned, I want to know if I can use Thread and Observer Pattern instead of Swingworker to keep Swing responsive? Thank You

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use Thread and Observer Pattern to keep Swing responsive?

I don't know what that pattern is. However, the GUI must be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). The SwingWorker does this for you. It creates a separate Thread and provides you with an API to make sure the GUI get updated on the EDT.

If you want to use a Thread, that is fine. But then anytime your code needs to update the GUI it is your responsibility to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to make sure the code gets invoked on the EDT.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I mean I'd like to use Thread along with Observable And Observers pattern. Sorry for misleading.